# Hover image doesn't show up after i updated my theme

Tags: css, hover

This is my code in style.css related to the image and the hover image.

```
#gallery_prettyphoto.portfolio a span
{
z-index: 2000;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 98%;
display: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio .gallery_2columns a span.image_hover
{background: black url("images/gallery_hover/hover_image_big.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

Everything was fine till i updated my theme to newer version. I checked if the hover_image_big.png was missing, no, the file is there.

Comment: What theme are talking about? Is this code from the theme? What are the differences?

Comment: its King Size wordpress theme

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently and it took me a long time to find the solution, but it turns out that you have to use the write the css like this:

```
.portfolio .gallery_2columns a span.image_hover
{
background: black;
background: url("..images/gallery_hover/hover_image_big.png") no-repeat center center;

}
```

I hope this helps!